# Django Many to Many Field Set in Model Save Method

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to override the save method in a model with logic to update a couple of many to many fields. Using print statements I can see values updating as expected but the values are not persisted after save.

In the below model the change_access_flag is changing as expected with a signal, the prints are executing with the appropriate values, but the allowed_departments and allowed_communities fields are not updating with the printed values.

**Model**

```
class Person(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    full_name = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=50)
    payroll_id = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=20)
    position = models.ForeignKey(Position, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    primary_community = models.ForeignKey(Community, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="primary_community")
    region = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=RegionChoices.choices, blank=True, null=True)
    allowed_communities = models.ManyToManyField(Community, blank=True, related_name="allowed_community")
    allowed_departments = models.ManyToManyField(Department, blank=True)
    access_change_flag = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.first_name} {self.user.last_name}'

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "People"
        ordering = ['position__position_code', 'user__last_name', 'full_name']

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        #Set Full Name field
        if self.user.last_name:
            self.full_name = f'{self.user.first_name} {self.user.last_name}'
        
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

        #Change flag set in signals, set for events that require updating access settings
        if self.access_change_flag:
            self.access_change_flag = False

            #Allowed community access
            access_level = self.position.location_access_level
            self.allowed_communities.clear()
            if access_level == 'R':
                if self.primary_community.community_name == '#':
                    region = self.region
                else:
                    region = self.primary_community.region
                if region is not None:
                    communities = Community.objects.filter(region=region)
                    self.allowed_communities.set(communities)
                self.allowed_communities.add(self.primary_community)
            elif access_level == 'A':
                communities = Community.objects.filter(active=True)
                self.allowed_communities.set(communities)
            else:
                communities = self.primary_community
                self.allowed_communities.add(communities)

            print(self.allowed_communities.all())

            #Allowed department access
            dept_access = self.position.department_only_access
            if dept_access:
                depts = [self.position.department]
            else:
                depts = Department.objects.filter(active=True)
            self.allowed_departments.set(depts)

            print(self.allowed_departments.all())
            super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I have tried variations of set, clear, add, moving the super.save() around, and placing the logic in a signal but nothing seems to work. I have tested initiating save from both a model form through a view and admin.

Answer (score 0):

Let me answer in quotes. You can find the source in [this section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods).

> If you wish to update a field value in the save() method, you may also
> want to have this field added to the update_fields keyword argument.
> This will ensure the field is saved when update_fields is specified.

Also read [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/instances/#specifying-which-fields-to-save)

> Specifying update_fields will force an update.

So try to call the `super().save(*args, **kwargs)` method at the end with defining the argument `update_fields`. This will force the update of your model regarding the specified fields.

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Ok, then the problem is, that you cannot save m2m fields to a model that is not saved yet. I know that you call `super().save(*args, **kwargs)` before, but maybe you have to reload that saved model. I think you would better put this logic inside your ModelForm. There you have the method `f.save_m2m()`. I guess [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) describes why you are struggeling.

Comment: I tried specifying the update_fields and got the following error: 
ValueError: The following fields do not exist in this model, are m2m fields, or are non-concrete fields: allowed_communities, allowed_departements
My understanding (fairly new and something is not working) is that save() and add() should be handling the save on the m2m fields because the m2m is not actually stored in this table, its stored in a separate hidden table.

Comment: I don't  think my use case would work with being contained to a form, but maybe there is a better way to model this out. I am trying to set access to locations and departments, where both could be one, multiple, or all and then flag to run this with signals. Changes in other models like a location changing region or a position changing department need to trigger to update access for people impacted.

Comment: Ok, try this: 1. Assign all fields that are not m2m fields. 2. call `super().save(*args, **kwargs)` with specifying `update_fields`. 3. fetch object from database with: `Person.objects.get(<your-logic>)` and assign the m2m fields to that newly fetched object. Reason still being that m2m fields can not be assigned to an Object that is not yet in DB

Comment: Still no luck. The person object is definitely already in the database, the access_change_flag is on a signal that verifies that and I have been testing updating existing records. I tried moving the super().save(update_fields=['access_change_flag'],*args, **kwargs) to just below switching the access_change_flag to False, then getting the Person object, running the previous code on the person object instead of self, then saving the person object.

Comment: Do you only have the problem with `allowed_communities` but not with `allowed_departments`? Because then the reason would be that you defined `related_name="allowed_community"`. If this is not it I am out of ideas...

Comment: Appreciate all the suggestions, has helped me not go around in the same circles trying to troubleshoot. I was worried there may be the issue as well but I am having the same problem with allowed_departments. I tried different variations using the related_name but they all throw errors. From what I have seen in the docs the related name seems to only be used when accessing from model side without the Many to Many field, Community in this case.